# Software (or commandLine) that dynamically runs dotnet code

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dynamic

I once heard about a software that could **dynamically run dotnet instructions** (C#, if I remember well) **on its command line**, e.g when entering `1==1`, the output would be `true`.

I don't remember the name of this soft, and sometimes one just wants to know the result of a given instruction, without having to create a new program, compiling it and run it...

I would happily take the challenge to make a soft like this on my own later, but for now on I'd just like to find this soft.

Does anyone know its name, or another app which would achieve the same result? (Don't tell me PowerShell, I'm searching for something more handy..Thanks)

---

**EDIT**
For those who use Visual Studio and who didn't know (I just learnt about it), you can also use the [Immediate Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It even allows you to get intellisense in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you mean the Mono [C# Repl](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl)?

Answer (score 3):

The mono project has the [CsharpRepl](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl) project - it is

> the C# interactive shell that is part of Mono's C# compiler. An interactive shell is usually referred to as a read eval print loop or repl.

You may also be thinking about [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell):

> Windows PowerShell is Microsoft's task automation framework, consisting of a command-line shell and associated scripting language built on top of, and integrated with the .NET Framework.

Comment: Jon already mentioned C#Repl, I think I'll go for it. As for PowerShell, it is not very handy for just running some .NET instructions. Thx for answering

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft's “Roslyn” project](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/10/19/introducing-the-microsoft-roslyn-ctp.aspx) includes a C# Interactive window for Visual Studio 2010:

> You can invoke the C# Interactive window from View -> Other Windows ->
>   C# Interactive Window. The Interactive window is powered by the new C#
>   language service. The architecture of Roslyn is flexible enough to
>   allow many of the IDE features such as IntelliSense and refactorings
>   to work the same in a normal editor and in the Interactive window.

It is effectively a command-line REPL for C# all within VS.